# In React how to prevent to use function onClick if width of web browser is less than

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

On mobile device my function onClick has two roles (open/close Menu and status changing  of my Hamburger menu. However both states working in the background if my navigation is set up for desktops screens also. I would like to  prevent to use function onClick if width of web browser is less than 757px;

Here is my code:

```
const [showMobileMenu, setShowMobileMenu] = useState(false);
const [navBarStatus, setNavBarStatus] = useState(false);

const onClick = () => {
    setShowMobileMenu(!showMobileMenu);
    setNavBarStatus(!navBarStatus);
  }
```

I have tried to add additionall condition to function onClick but it is not the right way :(

```
const onClick = () => {
        if (innerWidth < 757)
        setShowMobileMenu(!showMobileMenu);
        setNavBarStatus(!navBarStatus);
      }
```

Edit:
Problem solved. Object window was missing in syntax

```
const onClick = () =>{
    if (window.innerWidth<757) {
    setShowMobileMenu(!showMobileMenu);
    setNavBarStatus(!navBarStatus);
    }
  }
```

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-hook/media-query try this

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-responsive

Comment: how about an early return when `window.innerWidth` is less than `Xpx` , like `if(window.innerWidth < 757) {return}  //if not do something`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `window.matchMedia("(max-width: 757px)")` in your on click function . If you are using material-ui use [material-ui/withWidth](https://material-ui.com/customization/breakpoints/#withwidth.)

or use npm packages like [media-query-react](https://www.npmjs.com/package/media-query-react)

Answer (score 1):

hide the button for width less than 757px and show another button for mobile device and set separate onClick functions for them:

```
@media (max-width: 757px) {
  .mobile-button {
    display:inline;
  }
  .desktop-button {
    display:none;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 757px) {
  .mobile-button {
    display:none;
  }
  .desktop-button {
    display:inline;
  }
}
```